# PayPal API login error - "Sorry, we can't log you in.."

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using the paypal api login with this:

```
paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {
  login.render ({
    "appid":"myAppID",
    "authend": "sandbox",
    "scopes":"email",
    "containerid":"lippButton",
    "locale":"en-us",
    "returnurl":"myReturnUrl"
  });
});
```

when I click on lippButton paypal opens with forms for email and password. When they are filled in I get the error:

> Sorry, we can't log you in. If you think there's a problem with your
>   account, contact us and we'll help resolve it.

Even though If I redirect the user to login/complete payment it is fine. Any ideas as to what the problem is?

EDIT:

Seems like it may just be the sandbox api is down. I went here:

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/openid/php?success=true&env=sandbox

and clicked "Try it" then clicked on the link for step 2, which pops up an identical login form that I am using and the error message persists there as well.

EDIT:

Can anyone explain how I can log in to paypal, but not from their sandbox using my paypal credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. For anyone in the future with this same problem (I'm assuming many will because it is directly following their walk through), you seem to not be able to log in via "sandbox" mode (even though their provided code sample has authend: "sandbox" in it).

Simply put in your live credentials INSTEAD of your sandbox credentials. The log in should look like this (There should be no 'authend: "sandbox"' now):

```
paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {
  login.render ({
    "appid":"myAppID", //Use your live client ID, not your sandbox client ID.
    //No authend needed.
    "scopes":"email",
    "containerid":"lippButton",
    "locale":"en-us",
    "returnurl":"myReturnUrl"
  });
});
```

And the login now works and allows you to login.